# Zurb Foundation ios single column

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation css framwork.

For some reason when I go to the site using an iPhone the Header and navigation has a single column layout with width around 350px.  The Header and navigation looks fine when I use a browser resize.

My problem is that the "Search Diamonds" panel was a min-width of about 700.

Is there a way I can make the header to expand the width in iPhone?

[image: Search Diamon panel]

Comment: We're using Foundation for a project right now as well. If use the `.small-12` class on your elements, they should expand to full width in smaller views. `<div class="row"><div class="large-12 small-12 columns"></div></div>`

Comment: Post your `<head>`, did you set the screen width?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this issue only on iphone? Try to use media queries to set header width to 100%. 
You can also try with !important.
Do you use "row" class property??

Show us some markup pls

Comment: Yes, the issue is with iPhone only.  It is fine when I resize the browser window.  http://beta.ouroborodiamonds.com/